# MVC best practice for view validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

What is considered best practice for the following example:

- Change Password - Normal, enter username, current password, new password, confirm password
- Change Password - Password recovery, email has link that goes to this page sending a parameter which contains lets say username and new system changed password, View shows only new password and confirm password.
- Change Password - The above link has an invalid param and shows that this link is broken

Are these 3 separate views? Or the same view with multiple route options?

```
ActionResult ChangePassword()
ActionResult ChangePassword(string token)
{
// if bad token show this error view partial? set viewdata item and let cshtml decide what to show?
}
```

Or is a situation like this not really all that logical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would separate it into 2 pages:

Change Password

- users always enters old password and new one, new one twice for confirmation
- no need to get username because they should be authenticated already
- do not allow URL parameters to pre-populate values
- use a CSRF token

Reset Password

- only linked to from email with valid unique param
- user only enters new password, twice for confirmation
- no need to get username, URL param set by email already identifies user
- do not use URL params to send anything else, e.g. temp passwords or usernames
- no need to use CSRF token, other unique param already blocks against forgery

These two pages seem to operate differently enough that I think you would be better off using separate views, actions, & view models. If you get to the end though, there is nothing wrong with refactoring to remove duplication, but I would predict they will not be as similar as you anticipate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could get away with a single View, you just need to build a robust enough ViewModel:

```
 public class ChangePasswordViewModel(){
     public string OldPasswordHash {get; set;} //Remember never to store password in clear text
     public string NewPassword{ get; set; }
     public string RecoveryToken { get; set; }
 }
```

Based on these properties, you should have all you need to flesh out the presentation logic in your View to cover off all the use cases you describe above. Let me know if you need further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best validation for `ASP.NET MVC` will be `Validation Attributes` on the properties you will like to validate.